# How can we validate a Postgres database backup is not corrupted?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds, google-cloud-sql, vacuum

Is there a efficient way to check if the `Postgres` backups (for managed services like `RDS` and `Cloudsql`) are not corrupted?

Currently one of the ways we are implementing this check is in the following way:

- spin up a new DB from the `backup` and
- run a `vacuum`
- if the vacuum runs successful we are considering the backup is not corrupted
- delete the test DB

Does this sound like a valid approach and any better solution to this?

PS: GCP has this open source tool to test on their end, but did not understand how we can implement or use it on a managed PG instance.
https://github.com/google/pg_page_verification

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think you are doing the right thing. Another option would be to restore the backup and run a `pg_dump -f /dev/null` on the resulting database. But that would not check for index corruption.

Answer (score 1):

In Google Cloud SQL the `PostgreSQL Page Verification tool` runs automatically[1] on your backups, but if it makes you feel more comfortable  then you can run it yourself.

[1] https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/verifying-postgresql-backups-made-easier-new-open-source-tool

Answer (score 0):

Regarding Amazon RDS, there is no need to check corruption.

The RDS service is managed and theoretically guarantees a snapshot is valid when you create the snapshot.

If you would like to manually check the integrity, the process you've outlined is a sure-fire way at a high level.

At a low level, [`pg_checksums`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/app-pgchecksums.html) is also a great way to check integrity (which the `pg_page_verification` tool you mention uses).

---

Disclaimer: I am aware of situations where RDS snapshots have become corrupted in very, very rare cases over the years but they have been extremely rare & ultimately, compensation has been offered due to a breach of the SLA.

This should, however, not be a worry [99.95%](https://aws.amazon.com/rds/sla/) of the time.

Answer (score 0):

To verify RDS snapshot just restore database from it. As far as I know AWS relies on an official tools for PostgreSQL database.

For a database backup verification there is [pg_verifybackup](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgverifybackup.html) tool.

> pg_verifybackup is used to check the integrity of a database cluster backup taken using pg_basebackup against a backup_manifest generated by the server at the time of the backup.

A dumped database with `pg_dump` you could verify like: `cat dump.sql | psql`.